# Apache - RewriteRule "$(.*)^" pattern doesn't work with empty requests

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do some URL Rewriting with Apache2 and PHP, the problem is that I made an .htaccess file that uses rewrite_mod, here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webroot/index.php [QSA,L]
```

The `^(.*)$` pattern should match everything, but it doesn't match empty requests, and I don't know why.

To give you an exemple, here the `/root` folder is were the .htaccess file is.

- Request `/root/anything` matches;
- Request `/root/some/thing` matches too;
- Request `/root/` doesn't match.

Here, the `/root/` request should match as the pattern `^(.*)$` means "Match any characters from 0 times to any amount of times".

Does anyone know why it doesn't match empty requests?

I'm currently running LAMP under Linux Mint.

Comment: What exactly does that folder `webroot` in you substitution correspond to?

Comment: Are there any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: `webroot` is the folder that contains `index.php` and the website's content (images, scripts...). The `.htaccess` is **a level above** the `webroot` folder. So the path to the `.htaccess`file is `/root/.htaccess`, and the path to `index.php` is `/root/webroot/index.php`. And there aren't any other rules in the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# handles landing page
RewriteRule ^/?$ webroot/index.php [L]

# handles rest
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . webroot/index.php [L]
```

`mod_dir` module if runs before `mod_rewrite` and adds `DirectoryIndex` handler to landing page i.e. `/index.php` thus blocking execution of your rule due to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition.

Comment: It works, thank you for answering quickly. Is there a way to ensure that `mod_dir` **runs after** `mod_rewrite` in order to avoid this problem and have a permanent fix?

Comment: Internal operations of Apache like loading various modules are in user's control. Consider this as permanent fix as I've seen rules like above being shipped with many commercial software as well.